# Filter with terniary operator

Tags: c#, lambda, operators

I have a method

```
AddOrUpdateList(this List<T> list, T scope, Func<T, bool>, Func<T, bool> when = null){
    T item = default;
    if (when == null)
        list.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Equals(scope)); //Check Single
    else
        item = list.SingleOrDefault(when);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I'm going to use it I have two possible starts:

1. I receive an `element` which `element.Title` is something, so I use the `Title` as filter
2. I receive an `element` which has no title, so I need to get the last one from a List

I was thinking to use terniary operator and lambda to create a filter that contemplates both cases.

What I came up with is:

```
var filter = (element.Title != "")
   ? (Func<T, bool>)(e => e.Title == element.Title)
   : (Func<T, bool>)(e = list.Select(ele => ele).Last());
```

But that gives me: `Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Func<T, bool>'`

Any idea or help you can give me??

Im pretty new to C# and Linq so I don't understand to well how some things should work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `e = list` -- you meant `e => list`. That said `list.Select(ele => ele).Last()` is pointless: why not do `list.Last()` (assuming that `list` is a collection of bools?)

Comment: list is a List of object of one type

Comment: ... and is that one type `bool`? Right now, I can't work out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a method that add or update existing elements using the Title of the elements as a filter. But i have some elements that have no title, so they must update the last element from the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current filter is

```
var filter = (element.Title != "")
   ? (Func<T, bool>)(e => e.Title == element.Title)
   : (Func<T, bool>)(e = list.Select(ele => ele).Last());
```

But `e = list.Select(ele => ele).Last()` is not a `Func<T, bool>`. In fact, it is not a function at all. As @canton7 said, you need to use the arrow notation (`=>`)to create a lambda. Moreover, even if that line was a lambda, it would be of type `Func<T, T>`,
since it simply returns the last item in a list of items of type T; it does not return a bool at all!

Is this more what you want?

```
var filter = (element.Title != "")
   ? (Func<T, bool>)(e => e.Title == element.Title)
   : (Func<T, bool>)(e => e.Title == list.Last().Title);
```

Comment: Ill check tomorrow but i think that should work. Thanks

Comment: I try it and it worked flawlessly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What type of `element`? So, `AddOrUpdateList(Func<T, bool>)` uses T as type of some generic code. When you have concrete element, you should know what type of code. And set a concrete class name.

If you show more code, I will try to help you.

May be I сlimbing out of business, but it seems strange. Acording to method name, you want to Add element if it is not exist or update it if it already in list.

So, here is an example of typicaly such method implementation.

```
public void AddOrUpdate<T, K>(this List<T> list, T element, Func<T, K> keySelector, Action<T, T> mapFunction) : T new()
{
    var elementKey = keySelector(element);
    var elementForUpdate = list.FirstOrDefault(x => keySelector(x) == elementKey);

    var exists = elementForUpdate != null;

    if (!exists)
    {
        var newElement = new T();
        list.Add(newElement);
        elementForUpdate = list.Last();
    }

    mapFunction(elementForUpdate, element);
}
```

So, then in other part of code you can use it like:

```
...
var itemToAdd = new ClassWithTitle { Title = "Title 1"};
list.AddOrUpdate(itemToAdd , x => x.Title, (destination, origin) =>
{
    //Logic to map fields
    destination.Title = origin.Title;
    destination.SomeOtherField = origin.SomeOtherField;
})
...
```

**Please, pay attention.**

One more option, if you work with list (not with database), you can use method `IndexOf()` then this method will very simple.

```
public void AddOrUpdate<T, K>(this List<T> list, T element, Func<T, K> keySelector)
{
    var elementKey = keySelector(element);
    var elementFounded = list.FirstOrDefault(x => keySelector(x) == elementKey);

    var exists = elementForUpdate != null;

    if (!exists)
    {
        //IMPORTANT: Here you add element that sended to method. You should take it into consideration. 
        //If you want to add a clone of this object, implement interface IClonable and use this method like   list.Add(element.Clone());
        list.Add(element);
        return;
    }

    var indexOfFoundedElement = list.IndexOf(elementFounded);

     //IMPORTANT: Here you replace element that sended to method. You should take it into consideration. 
    list[indexOfFoundedElement] = element;
}
```

Comment: This is more suited as a comment

Comment: element is of type T, because it dependes from where I call the method. Basically I have various list of containing objects. Each list is from one different type, so the method must be T, to order the various list that I have. I updated the questions to show more content